# Extracting values from 2 arrays with Javascript and removing duplicate 'titles'...?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is probably a simple question, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

I have two corresponding arrays, e.g.

```
'0' => "Difficulty"
'1' => "Difficulty"
'2' => "Difficulty"
'3' => "Specialty"
'4' => "Specialty"
'5' => "Specialty"
'6' => "imagecontent"
'7' => "ShowMe"
'8' => "ShowMe"
```

and:

```
 '0' => "Easy"
'1' => "Average"
'2' => "Difficult"
'3' => "Specialty name x"
'4' => "Specialty name y"
'5' => "Specialty name z"
'6' => "All"
'7' => "Questions I have never seen"
'8' => "Questions I have answered incorrectly"
```

The arrays correspond to filter settings for a group of questions; the first array relates to the 'Filter Title', and the second array relates to the selection for each filter - 'Filter Value'. There can be multiple selections for each filter, which is why there are duplicate instances of the Filter Titles 'Difficulty' and 'Specialty', for example.

I want to output the values to a page, in order to show the user what filter settings they've applied.

I started off with the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < filterID.length; i++) {
$( "div.currentFS" ).append("<div class='fs " + [i] + "'>" + filterID[i] + ": " +  filterValue[i] + "</div>");
}
```

...which works fine, if there is only one instance of each Filter Title. However, if there are multiple selections within a filter, the Filter Title is output the same number of times as the Filter Value.

Instead, I'd like to group the Filter Values under one Filter Title, so instead of

Difficulty: Easy
Difficulty: Average
Difficulty: Hard

...I'd get:

Difficulty: Easy, Average, Hard.

I don't believe this should be particularly complicated, but can't work out the most efficient way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

John.

Comment: Can you combine the two arrays into a dictionary?

Comment: I've no idea how to do that - I'll look it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use parallel arrays, then the simplest is probably just to keep track of the current ID, and when it changes, add a new heading:

```js
var filterID = [
  "Difficulty",
"Difficulty",
"Difficulty",
"Specialty",
"Specialty",
"Specialty",
"imagecontent",
"ShowMe",
"ShowMe"
];
var filterValue = [
"Easy",
"Average",
"Difficult",
"Specialty name x",
"Specialty name y",
"Specialty name z",
"All",
"Questions I have never seen",
"Questions I have answered incorrectly"
];

var current = ""; // Keep track of the current ID

for (var i = 0; i < filterID.length; i++) {
    if (filterID[i] !== current) { // If the ID in the loop isn't current...
        current = filterID[i];     // store it...
        $(document.body).append("<br><b>"+ current + ": </b>"); // and add it.
    }
    $(document.body).append("<span>" + filterValue[i] + "</span>");
}
```

```css
span { padding: 8px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This did the trick perfectly - thank you (and I'll let you off for killing my father).

Comment: @getnorthern: I thought you looked familiar! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two arrays, why not use an object?

```
var filters = {
    Difficulty: ["Easy", "Average", "Difficult"],
    Specialty: ["Specialty name x", "Specialty name y", "Specialty name z"],
    imagecontent: ["All"],
    ShowMe: ["Questions I have never seen",
            "Questions I have answered incorrectly"]
};
```

Or, if you can't start off with the data in that format, you can
convert it:

```js
var titles = ["Difficulty", "Difficulty", "Difficulty", "Specialty",
        "Specialty", "Specialty", "imagecontent", "ShowMe", "ShowMe"];

var values = ["Easy", "Average", "Difficult", "Specialty name x",
        "Specialty name y", "Specialty name z", "All",
        "Questions I have never seen",
        "Questions I have answered incorrectly"];

var filters = {};

titles.forEach(function(title, index){
    var value = values[index];
    filters[title] = filters[title] || [];
    filters[title].push(value);
});

console.log(filters);

// And to print:
Object.keys(filters).forEach(function(title){
    console.log(title + ': ' + filters[title].join(', ') + '.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been alluded to in the comments, you'll get much cleaner code if you combine the two arrays into an object first:

```
var filters = {},
    i, ID, value,
    filter;

for (i = 0; i < filterValue.length; i++) { // iterate through the current arrays
    ID = filterID[i];
    value = filterValue[i];

    // if this is the first time we've seen this ID, create an array to hold its values
    if (!filters.hasOwnProperty(ID)) {
        filters[ID] = [];
    }

    filters[ID].push(value); // push the latest value to the array
}
```

That will give you an object called `filters` that looks like:

```
{
    "Difficulty":   ["Easy", "Average", "Difficult"],
    "Specialty":    ["Specialty name x", "Specialty name y", "Specialty name z"],
    "imagecontent": ["All"],
    "ShowMe":       ["Questions I have never seen", "Questions I have answered incorrectly"]
}
```

You can then output it much more easily:

```
for (var filter in filters) {
    $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("fs")
        .text(filter + ": " + filters[filter].join(', '))
        .appendTo("div.currentFS");
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d1mma20k/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider object oriented approach with following data structure:-

```
var filters = [
    filter: { category: "Difficulty", values: ["Easy", "Average", "Difficult"] ,class: "difficultyClass"  },
    filter: { category: "Specialty", values: ["Specialty name x", "Specialty name y", "Specialty name z"], class: "difficultyClass"}   
];
```

Then further down you could do something like:-

```
var currentFS = $( "div.currentFS" );
for (filter in filters) {
   var myFilterDiv = "<div class='fs " + filter.class+ "'>"+filter.category;
   for(value in values) {
      currentFS.append(myFilterDiv + ":" + value +"</div>");  
   }
}
```